# MongoDB community edition for SAAS based application

Tags: mongodb

We are going to develop a SAAS based application using NoSQL (Preferably MongoDB community edition). When we download the community edition we observed that the MongoDB license got changed to SSPL. And it highlighted that we cannot modify the server code and cannot run MongoDB as a service.

Hence I just wanted to confirm here that, we don't do any change in the server code, we do only store data in MongoDB and host them in a cloud environment and make our web application as a service to the customers (SAAS). So it wont violate anything in the SSPL right.